# How to plot grouped dataframe for multiple years and countries?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, pandas-groupby

This is the grouped DataFrame I am working on. I have several variables for several countries, and years. How do I plot a line chart using matplotlib that shows the evolution of the variable "gdp_share" over time for the different countries?

I have grouped the DataFrame using:

```
data = data.groupby(["year", "Country"]).mean()


              gdp_share military_exp    pop gdp gdp_pc  military_pc
year    Country                     
2010    China   2.0 138028416.0 1359755 13615620000 10226.87    101.509769
        France  2.0 54569820.0  63027   2559460000  39449.38    865.816555
        Germany 1.0 41488240.0  80895   3587004000  43928.90    512.865319
        Israel  6.0 15044490.0  7426    241692000   32665.37    2025.921088
2011    China   2.0 149022400.0 1367480 14957177000 11180.83    108.975927
        France  2.0 53235512.0  63344   2612677000  40078.52    840.419172
        Germany 1.0 40301428.0  80934   3718288000  45633.17    497.954234
        Israel  6.0 15582490.0  7569    254299000   33733.19    2058.725063
2012    China   2.0 161796896.0 1375199 16211650000 12058.70    117.653442
        France  2.0 52499752.0  63640   2617451000  39961.04    824.948963
        Germany 1.0 41262500.0  81066   3736582000  45771.68    508.998840
        Israel  6.0 15728390.0  7699    259884000   33840.45    2042.913365
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_xticks(data.year.unique())
data.groupby(["year", "Country"]).mean()['gdp_share'].unstack().plot(ax=ax)
```

Comment: Consider including a short description of your code

Comment: It keeps throwing this error: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'year'

Comment: How come? you have column `year`. then `data.year` will not raise error.

Comment: I ran all the cells again and this is the error now.. Empty 'DataFrame': no numeric data to plot

Comment: That's weird because I made sure to turn all numbers into floats:

`for col in data.select_dtypes('object').columns:
 
    data[col] = pd.to_numeric(data[col], errors = 'coerce', downcast='float')`

Comment: Then please check data.info() to see which columns remain non-numeric type after convert.